# Continuous integration with pipelines

Tags: android, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, bamboo

I'm an Android developer with no experience with CI/CD pipelines, we are currently using GitLab for our source control. Every feature that I'm working on (I'm the only android developer at the moment) I'm doing on a separate branch (branching the master and working on separate branch). We know it's not the best solution but this is how we are working now and we want to improve that.

A few issues that we currently have right now:

1) As I mentioned before, every feature is currently sits on a different branch. When it's time to release a version for testing/release we want to work only with one apk instead of multiple apks and also for every apk we need to increase the version number or change the application name which is not practical in a long run. How can this process be more sufficient and more effective?

2) This solution needs to be compatible with iOS as well.

There are several possibilities such as Jenkins, Bamboo, Azure pipelines and GitLab CI. I'm not sure which will be a better choice for our needs.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple branching strategies aka git workflows well discussed and tested over tine.. Here is an article at medium that discuss them in detail - https://medium.com/@patrickporto/4-branching-workflows-for-git-30d0aaee7bf

This flow relies on two branches

**master —** this branch contains production code. All development code is merged into master in sometime.

**develop —** this branch contains pre-production code. When the features are finished then they are merged into develop.

I would personally recommend this strategy that uses develop branch- so your code goes to feature branch, then develop and then you label every release on develop.

Every such release is synced to master post-release. You can read more on the medium post.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean to go with GIT Flow? For every release we will need to create separate feature branches, after I will complete to work on them I will merge them into develop branch and release an incremental version for testing. If everything went well I will merge the develop to the master. In this case the release version will be easier. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @DemoDemo : that's right. Additionally, you would want to set up CI jobs to run on your feature ranches as well as the develop branch, to build and test as much as you can before merging down to the next branch. You might or might not rebuild on the master branch for the final packages, depending on how you merge and whether your commit levels are preserved.

Comment: @PatriceM. Noted, Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0):

there are many strategies that can work for your requirements. It depends on your team size.

### one possible workflow for master - release mode

1. every developer works on `master` branch. they need to `fetch` and `rebase` the local change to latest commit of `master` branch before push the local change to remote, which means the `push` must be a fast-forward push.
2. create a release branch like `release_v1.1.0` when you need a release version. developer fix the bugs on release branch, and also `cherry-pick` all the bug fix commits to `master` branch as well.
3. developers can also keep working on new feature on `master` branch while release branch in test-fix lifecycle.

### another way for product - develop separated mode

1. developer works on their own branch, and keep rebase and merge the finished changes to `develop` branch. again, it need to be a fast-forward push when do the merge.
2. use `master` branch as release branch. merge from `develop` branch and tag the branch when release to product environment.
3. remember to `cherry-pick` the fix on master back to develop as well.

### github workflow

use the build-in workflow in GitHub.